# How do i mix up states and props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

I am trying to build an application using "Rick and Morty API"

What I am trying to do:

1) render character names in the webpage using the REST API

2) somehow i managed to do it, but I got so confused.

3) I have two components one is "card.js" which creates a card, and another is "cardlist.js" which loops over the card.js component to render all the names using map function.

My Card.js component :

```
import React from "react";

class Card extends React.Component {
  state = {
    id: "",
    name: "",
    status: "",
    species: "",
    type: "",
    gender: "",
    imgURL: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.id;
    const name = this.props.name;
    const status = this.props.status;
    const species = this.props.species;
    const gender = this.props.gender;
    const type = this.props.type;
    const imgURL = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/${id}.jpeg`;
    //console.log(this.props);

    this.setState({
      id: id,
      name: name,
      status: status,
      species: species,
      gender: gender,
      type: type,
      imgURL: imgURL
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ID: {this.state.id}</h1>
        <img src={this.state.imgURL} alt="Image failed to load" />
        <h1>NAME: {this.state.name}</h1>
        <h2>STATUS: {this.state.status}</h2>
        <h3>SPECIES: {this.state.species}</h3>
        <h3>GENDER: {this.state.props}</h3>
        <h4>TYPE: {this.state.type}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

My CardList.js component is below:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Card from "./Card";

class CardList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=20",
    character: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({
      character: res.data.results
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.character.map(character => (
          <Card
            key={character.id}
            id={character.id}
            name={character.name}
            status={character.status}
            species={character.species}
            gender={character.gender}
            type={character.type ? character.type : "Unknown"}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardList;
```

NOTE: - Somehow,the application is fully working .

The issues I am facing, and why it is so confusing:

1) Failing to understand, how my card list is rendering the details like "id={character.id}" as it does not contains any props.

2) why I have access to props in my "card.js" component. when I try to console.log(props); in my card.js component, I get all the JSON results and its totally shocking to me. how can i access the JSON result under the props property IN MY CARD.JS component, and how it is related to cardlist.js component.

3) I have not written any props in either the return in the card or card list component, so how is it connecting to each other.

Comment: you mean to say you have the result data of that api when you console.log props? If so then can you please add the log that you are getting on `console.log(props)`

Comment: what difference would that make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This data is in your state :) There is no need to pass a prop because you're rendering based on the state data

2,3) you can access props in card js because you pass data here:

```
<Card
            key={character.id}
            id={character.id}
            name={character.name}
            status={character.status}
            species={character.species}
            gender={character.gender}
            type={character.type ? character.type : "Unknown"}
          />
```

Comment: Yes sure, good insight, however, why do I have JSON results when I try to console.log(props) in my card.js component?

Comment: You fetch data and than you push it to the state. After that  it's passed to Card via props. You should be able to see the data you've passed through props so key,id,name,status,species,gender and type. Is it right ?

Comment: just to be clear, the state in card and state in cardlist are independent from each other. right?

Comment: Exactly. Your card.js has it's own state and your CardList has it's own state. The reason you see state data from CardList in Card.js props is because you pass it in CardList.js

Comment: could you please write down a stepwise, how are we jumping between components and passing data, what comes first ad what comes after?

Comment: 1) You fetch the data in CardList.js
2) You push results to the state object (still CardList.js)
3) You map over the state and you render a Card component for each character (still CardList.js)
4)You pass data as props to each card:
  <Card
            key={character.id}
            id={character.id}
            name={character.name}
            status={character.status}
            species={character.species}
            gender={character.gender}
            type={character.type ? character.type : "Unknown"}
          />
5) Passed data is available in Card component as a props

Comment: This literally explained everything well, just one more thing, the data is now available in card.js as props, where are we storing it

Comment: This data is still stored in CardList.js -> in state. From there - it's passed to Card Component
I hope my comments helped You :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I got my head around everything now!